# Three.js, преобразование .html в .exe

Tags: three.js, exe

Друзья, кто пользуется Three.js и конвертирует эти сцены в .exe, подскажите наиболее простой и эффективный продукт для этого (не исключаю, что под 3D они вовсе не все заточены.). Попробовала Webexe, сконвертировалось только html, никаких подгруженных файлов. Может, я что-то не так сделала... Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `nwjs` подойдёт

Comment: чтобы запустить сцену с three.js, где есть текстуры, *.gltf и т.п. нужен еще портативный веб сервер, в этом случае подойдет фреймворк NW.js, как писалось выше или Electron, у них под капотом Node.js. У меня получалось для самого простого примера приложение размером около 300Mb!